# Get lightness of ambiance with react-native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'd like to change color of my react-native (Android) interface when the ambiance lightness is low. Like it happens with Google Maps in navigation mode.

How can I obtain the needed information from the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, found a library for this:

https://github.com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-manager

For reference, trying to add this module to my app I encountered a problem described here:
https://github.com/kprimice/react-native-sensor-manager/issues/24

The solution is to add the required code in `MainApplication.java` instead of `MainActivity.java`